# C# string comparison issue

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I am working on a project to make a super basic programming language for fun. I am working on the print command, and it has 2 different options, a direct print, or printing from a stack. The program already has items in the stack, but whenever it runs a print command that prints from the stack, it skips over it. Here is my code:

```
if (String.Equals(cmds[pos], "print"))
{
    if (cmds[pos + 1].StartsWith("\""))
    {
        Console.Write(cmds[pos + 1].Replace("\"", "").Replace(@"\q", "\"").Replace(@"\n", "\n"));
        outPos = pos + 2;
    }
    else if (string.Equals(cmds[pos + 1], "stack"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(strStack.Pop());
        outPos = pos + 2;
    }
    else
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("HelloKreeKraw");
        outPos = pos + 1;
    }
}
```

and here are the commands:

```
push "Hi\n"
throw stack
push "Hello"
print stack
print "World!\n"
end
```

The push command pushes to the stack, and the end command ends the program. The program skips over the print stack for no reason. I tested everything it could be unless I'm missing something?

Edit:
The string.replace and cmds[pos + 1].StartsWith("\"") work just fine, but when it checks for the second word being stack, it randomly glitches out. I already found that to be the case.

Comment: yes, less nested if's, not sure what is the benefit of trying to learn by nesting if's.

Comment: Can you use breakpoints to check a few preliminary stuff first, e.g. `pos` is correct (since arrays are 0 based), `cmds` array is correctly split by spaces, etc.

Comment: this line make sure the Replace() is working `Console.Write(cmds[pos + 1].Replace("\"", "").Replace(@"\q", "\"").Replace(@"\n", "\n"));`

Comment: should if (String.Equals(cmds[pos], "print")) be if (String.StartsWith(cmds[pos], "print"))

Comment: When you debug your code, does this line hit? `if (cmds[pos + 1].StartsWith("\""))`

Comment: You should probably be doing it with regular expressions, see some introduction here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: Learn about State Machines, you can implement one in C# or use an already existing one, first explicitly define your tokens, have a list of tokens instead of having hard coded strings in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn, you need to grab a book on Lex and YACC/Bison.  Basically standard compiler theory is not being used here.  You need to build your grammar, (command -> variable -> New line) and then create your lexer to identify your tokens.  Parsing tokens to emit code/options is then a much better way to go.

By the way, if you are using C# you could have some real fun by building an expression tree first in your code and then only executing it at the end.  Much closer to building a real compiler :).

Then the easiest way is to use recursive descent on your implementation (rather than nested ifs...) to do what you are trying to do.  We could work with you to fix your string handling, but this is a solved problem with some far better tools to help you.